# Optional SSL in TYPO3

Tags: ssl, typo3

I want to make our TYPO3 v4.5 website accessible by HTTP and HTTPS. I already configured SSL for Apache and requesting the main page displays it... partially.

The baseurl within the page links to my http-site (and is not a https-URL), and therefore the browser won't load the css files, because they come from an unsafe part of my domain.

I believe I could switch my whole site to HTTPS, but don't want it. I would like that when the site is called by HTTP, all URLs are generated as http:// and when called over SSL, all urls should be generated as https:// URLs.

Did anybody achieve something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Use a TypoScript condition to output the base URL dependent on the used protocol:

```
config.baseURL = http://example.com
[globalString = ENV:HTTPS=on]
config.baseURL = https://example.com
[global]
```

That's a bit ugly (as both variants will not share caches), but [Protocol-relative  tags are not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908318/can-i-use-a-protocol-relative-base-tag). The only alternative (to baseURL) is [config.absRefPrefix](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#absrefprefix).